# Can someone solve this? I cant find a thing about it

Tags: string, integer, largenumber

Implement a data type to represent "large numbers" and operate with them. A "large number" is an integer that can have up to 200 digits. For internal representation of numbers will use strings. On these numbers are defined arithmetic operations (operators +, -, *), relational (>, <, = =, etc.). Build a program that exemplifies the usage of such numbers.

Comment: Which language do you want this program in?

Comment: What did you try to solve this? This is Q&A, we expect askers to show research effort (quote from the little downvote button tooltip: *"This question **does not show any research effort**; it is unclear or not useful"*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically they are asking you to create your own implementation of BigInteger
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Which represents VERY large numbers using Strings to avoid the limitations of binary represented numbers.  Math is performed on them using the digits directly similar to how you might do it using a pencil and paper.

Comment: Okay, so it's all about VERY large numbers. I had a doubt that might be a difference between large numbers and VERY large numbers. Thank you for the answer!